# Аналог WP unyson (типы полей)

Tags: php, laravel, cms, composer

Стоит задача создать набор типов полей для CMS. Например нужно создать управление разделом "Моя команда" значит создаем файлик и указываем какие поля должны быть на странице добавления/редактирования нового участника команды.

Что-то на подобии этого: http://manual.unyson.io/en/latest/options/built-in/introduction.html?highlight=types

Так вот вопрос в том стоит ли писать весь функционал с нуля или уже есть что-то подобное что можно установить через composer например...

Использую laravel. Другие фреймворки не предлагать.

Спасибо!

Comment: Так я сейчас не понял тебе нужны кастомизирование полей на странице или набор готовых тулсов ?

Comment: Насколько я помню в KodiCMS делали такую фичу, можешь скачать посмотреть как работает в проекте, отдельно пакет называется KodiComponents/module-datasource , оно или нет  ?

Comment: Очень интересно. Кажется это то что нужно. Спасибо, @Orange_shadow